# Hibernate _AUD Table - FOR statement from SELECT

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, liquibase

I have to update an hibernate _aud table manually using Liquibase and Postgres.

I will explain my algorithm:

FIRST : Select all distinct id from person_AUD table

```
select distinct id from product_aud;
```

SECOND: insert new records into product_aud based on the "id list".

So I would like to do something like this:

```
MY_IDs = select distinct id from product_aud; //My row list with id column
    for(int i=1;i <MY_IDs;i++ ) {
           INSERT INTO product_aud(id,rev,revtype,revend)
            VALUES (i, nextval ('hibernate_sequence'), 1, null)

    }
```

How can I do this using SQL only?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
insert into product_aud(id,rev,revtype,revend)
select persons.id, nextval ('hibernate_sequence'), 1, null
from (
    select distinct id from person_aud
) persons;
```

Comment: ok, thank you...and how can i get the same result using a function and cursor?

Comment: Not quite sure what do you mean by using "function and cursor".. You can put this insert statement into an sql file and call it with liquibase's sql change set.